# Email client with support of multiple answers

Tags: email, email-client

I am a mobile game developer, and have a specific need regarding the answers I give to my users emails:

I want to be able to select several emails from my Inbox (filtering them by tag or a keyword in the body, e.g. "German"), and send the same answer to every one of the senders (e.g. "Hi, the German version is out"), preferably in separate messages (one per user).

This feature is unavailable in all the clients I have tried: Gmail's webmail, Thunderbird and Postbox.

Another need is to be able to send "Canned responses" to frequently asked questions. This feature is already offered by Gmail labs.

**Is there any Windows email client, or Thunderbird plugin, that supports both of these needs ?**

Comment: How is this off-topic ??

Comment: I have a very specific need and ask which piece of software might fullfil it. This is certainly not an open or subjective question, as there is no widely known solution to my problem.

Comment: I found a solution: Batch Reply for Gmail is a Chrome add-on that does the job

Answer (score 1):

For batch sending, you should use an Email Service Provider like Campaign Monitor or MailChimp. In Campaign Monitor you can create custom fields (their country would be one in this case) for each subscriber, then batch send to all that match that criteria by segmenting your subscriber list.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm talking about mailing 10 users or so once in a while, so I think using a campagin service is overkill.

Comment: Understood. Although it doesn't automate any sending, Gmail has very powerful search and segmentation (labels). You can easily group and sub-group emails into labels (groups/tags). Gmail auto searches incoming email containing certain words, from certain people or other matches you can set up using the filters. You could easily make a 'German' label to contain all German customer emails for example.

Comment: I'm already using Gmail, but sending the same email to all the senders of 'German' labeled messages is tedious: I have to select them, then hit 'Filter messages like these', copy the senders list to a text editor to remove all 'OR's and send my message to this list fo recipients.

Comment: Seems like you need to group the senders, not the emails. Have you tried grouping your contacts into folders? Adding them in is not an automated process, but at least you only have to do it once for each customer. You can then easily send to the 'German' group in one go. By putting the 'German' email group in the bcc field, they won't be aware of who else is on the list, so it appears like it was sent just to them.

Comment: Sounds like a nice idea. The only problem is that I don't really know in advance which groups/folders I will need. I would really like to be able to automatically create groups based on a filter.

Comment: Here is the list of wildcards you can use to search your incoming mail. Create a filter and send them to a label. It won't add them to the contact group, but at least you can do your search automatically this way: [https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190)